# HTML CSS - display: inline-block can't center the container with % width

Tags: html, css

Creating my website and cant make my container with list of elements centerd if I want my grid responsive and have the display: block or display: inline-block and have a % width

heres a the situation im in. I want the grid with blocks to be responsive and have display: block/ display: inline-block (I have this bcs when u click on the button web scraping a button it will hide one of the blocks and I want it to float: left so one of the blocks doent center when one disperse)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#web-scraping").click(function(){

    if($("#web-s").hasClass("hide")){
        $('#web-s').removeClass('hide');
    }
    else{
        $("#web-s").addClass('hide')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: sofia_pro;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container{
    min-height: 65vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#hero{
    background-color: #32312F;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
#hero .hero{
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 50px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
#hero h1{
    display: block;
    width: fit-content;
    font-size: 5rem;
    position: relative;
    color: transparent;
    animation: text_reveal .5s ease forwards;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}


#hero h1 span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    animation: text_reveal_box 1s ease;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
#hero p{
    display: block;
    width: 40%;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-top: 60px;
    position: relative;
    color: transparent;
    animation: text_reveal .5s ease forwards;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

#hero .button-box{
    margin-top: 40px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 140px; 
}
#hero .cta{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    visibility: hidden;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    transition: .3s ease background-color;
    opacity: 1;
    animation: box_reveal .5s ease forwards;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

#hero .cta span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    animation: box_reveal_box 1s ease;
    animation-delay: .5s;
}
#hero .cta:hover{
    box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 1px #fff inset;
}

/*animation*/
@keyframes text_reveal_box{
    50%{
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    100%{
        width: 0;
        left: 100%;
    }
}
@keyframes box_reveal_box{
    50%{
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    100%{
        width: 0;
        left: 100%;
    }
}
@keyframes text_reveal{
    100%{
        color: #fff;
    }
}
@keyframes box_reveal{
    100%{
        visibility: visible;
    }
}

.down-pointer{
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    top: -160px;
    
}
.down-pointer .left{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transition: .5s;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: -2px 2px;
    color: #f6f6f6;
}
.down-pointer .left{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}


.work-container{
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    height: 1000px;
    max-width: 1300px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 00px;
    margin: 0px 60px;
    top: -100px;
    padding: 100px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    
}
.work-category{
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
.work-category button{
    text-transform: capitalize;
    border: 1px solid #32312F;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #32312F;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.work-category button:hover{   
}
#web-scraping{
    margin: auto 100px auto auto;
}
#web-design{
    margin: auto 0px auto 0px;
}
#web-animation{
    margin: auto auto auto 100px;
}
.work-block-container .hide{
    display: none;
}

.work-block-container-flex{
    
}
.work-block-container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    
}
.work-block{
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animation.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media-screen.css">
  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Starting-menu-->
    <section id=hero>
        <div class="hero">
            <div class="hero container">
                <div>
                    <h1>What I can do,<span></span></h1>
                    <h1>for your Business<span></span></h1>
                    <p><span>
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by 
                        the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point
                        of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution
                    </span></p>
                    <div class="button-box"><a href="#" type="button" class="cta">Contact Me<span></span></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End-->

    <!-- my work -->

    <section class="work-container">
        <a class="down-pointer" href="#"><span class="left"></span></a>
        <div class="work-category">
            <button id="web-scraping">Web Scraping</button>
            <button id="web-design">Web Design</button>
            <button id="web-animation">web animation</button>
        </div>

        <div class="work-block-container">
            <div class="work-block" id="web-s"></div>
            <div class="work-block" id="web-d"></div>
            <div class="work-block" id="web-s"></div>
            <div class="work-block" id="web-d"></div>
            <div class="work-block" id="web-d"></div>
            <div class="work-block" id="web-a"></div>
        </div>
        
           
        
    </section>
    <!-- my work end -->

    <!-- about me -->
    <div class="container about" id="">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <div class="about-me-info">
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- about me  end-->

    <!-- contact me -->
    
    <!-- contact me end -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). External links are ok, but only when the code is also in the question itself - this is because external links can change or break over time, making the question unhelpful to other users

Comment: You mean such centering? - https://ibb.co/jb1MM4M or this it? - https://ibb.co/9HvxMLN

Answer (score 1):

I think you use another `<div>` in your `container` so your flex or grid display just effect on that div!

try display flex or grid on that div or make your container as your element's parents.

Answer (score 0):

First, the ID for each element must be unique. I think you achieved this))

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#web-scraping").click(function(){
        $(".web-d").addClass("hide")
        $(".web-a").addClass("hide")
        $(".web-s").removeClass("hide")
    });
    $("#web-design").click(function(){
        $(".web-d").removeClass("hide")
        $(".web-a").addClass("hide")
        $(".web-s").addClass("hide")
    });
    $("#web-animation").click(function(){
        $(".web-d").addClass("hide")
        $(".web-a").removeClass("hide")
        $(".web-s").addClass("hide")
    });
});
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html{
    font-size: 10px;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container{
    min-height: 65vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#hero{
    background-color: #32312F;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
#hero .hero{
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 50px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
#hero h1{
    display: block;
    width: fit-content;
    font-size: 5rem;
    position: relative;
    color: transparent;
    animation: text_reveal .5s ease forwards;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}


#hero h1 span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    animation: text_reveal_box 1s ease;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
#hero p{
    display: block;
    width: 40%;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-top: 60px;
    position: relative;
    color: transparent;
    animation: text_reveal .5s ease forwards;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

#hero .button-box{
    margin-top: 40px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 140px;
}
#hero .cta{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    visibility: hidden;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    transition: .3s ease background-color;
    opacity: 1;
    animation: box_reveal .5s ease forwards;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

#hero .cta span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    animation: box_reveal_box 1s ease;
    animation-delay: .5s;
}
#hero .cta:hover{
    box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #fff inset;
}

/*animation*/
@keyframes text_reveal_box{
    50%{
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    100%{
        width: 0;
        left: 100%;
    }
}
@keyframes box_reveal_box{
    50%{
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    100%{
        width: 0;
        left: 100%;
    }
}
@keyframes text_reveal{
    100%{
        color: #fff;
    }
}
@keyframes box_reveal{
    100%{
        visibility: visible;
    }
}

.down-pointer{
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    top: -160px;

}
.down-pointer .left{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transition: .5s;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: -2px 2px;
    color: #f6f6f6;
}
.down-pointer .left{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}


.work-container{
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    height: 1000px;
    max-width: 1300px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 00px;
    margin: 0 60px;
    top: -100px;
    padding: 100px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;

}
.work-category{
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
.work-category button{
    text-transform: capitalize;
    border: 1px solid #32312F;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #32312F;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.work-category button:hover{
}
#web-scraping{
    margin: auto 100px auto auto;
}
#web-design{
    margin: auto 0 auto 0;
}
#web-animation{
    margin: auto auto auto 100px;
}

.work-block-container-flex{

}
.work-block-container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;

}
.work-block{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: 0.7s all;
}
.work-block.web-s{
    background-color: green;
}
.work-block.web-d{
    background-color: blue;
}
.work-block.web-a{
    background-color: red;
}
.work-block.web-s.hide{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.work-block.web-d.hide{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.work-block.web-a.hide{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Starting-menu-->
<section id=hero>
    <div class="hero">
        <div class="hero container">
            <div>
                <h1>What I can do,<span></span></h1>
                <h1>for your Business<span></span></h1>
                <p><span>
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by
                        the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point
                        of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution
                    </span></p>
                <div class="button-box"><a href="#" type="button" class="cta">Contact Me<span></span></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- End-->

<!-- my work -->

<section class="work-container">
    <a class="down-pointer" href="#"><span class="left"></span></a>
    <div class="work-category">
        <button id="web-scraping">Web Scraping</button>
        <button id="web-design">Web Design</button>
        <button id="web-animation">web animation</button>
    </div>

    <div class="work-block-container">
        <div class="work-block web-s"></div>
        <div class="work-block web-d"></div>
        <div class="work-block web-s"></div>
        <div class="work-block web-d"></div>
        <div class="work-block web-d"></div>
        <div class="work-block web-a"></div>
    </div>



</section>
<!-- my work end -->

<!-- about me -->
<div class="container about" id="">
    <h1>About</h1>
    <div class="about-me-info">
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- about me  end-->

<!-- contact me -->

<!-- contact me end -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```